# Ros, Rviz displays CubeList incorrect from MarkerArray

Tags: ros

i am using Ros and Rviz do display Markers. But for some reason the Markers are not displayed correctly. It looks like this:

[image]

I actually have no Idea why this is the case, does anybody have any idea. My Published Array looks like this:

```
rostopic echo /visualization/visualization_marker_array
header: 
  seq: 1
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs:         0
  frame_id: /robot_base_link
ns: ''
id: 0
type: 6
action: 0
pose: 
  position: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
  orientation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 1.0
scale: 
  x: 0.01
  y: 0.01
  z: 0.01
color: 
  r: 0.0
  g: 0.0
  b: 0.0
  a: 0.0
lifetime: 
  secs: 0
  nsecs:         0
frame_locked: False
points: 
  - 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
  - 
    x: 0.1
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
colors: 
  - 
    r: 1.0
    g: 0.0
    b: 0.0
    a: 1.0
  - 
    r: 0.0
    g: 1.0
    b: 0.0
    a: 1.0
text: ''
mesh_resource: ''
mesh_use_embedded_materials: False
---
```

Furthermore I am publishing the markerarray and i am subscribing in rviz. rostopic info confirms that.

Does anybody have an idea where i might be wrong, or why this is happening?
Thanks

Comment: It appears that the problem was not within the code, it was rather the fault of the workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine for me with RViz version 1.12.3 (kinetic). Your example is a bit confusing, though, as you mention that you are sending a MarkerArray but you show only a Marker ?!

I'm attaching a screenshot of rviz showing your cubes, and I created the message on the command line via `rostopic pub /visualization/visualization_marker_array visualization_msgs/Marker "{ header: {seq: 1, stamp: {secs: 0, nsecs: 0}, frame_id: /robot_base_link}, ns: '', id: 0, type: 6, action: 0, pose: { orientation: { w: 1.0 } }, scale: {x: 0.01, y: 0.01, z: 0.01}, points: [ {}, { x: 0.1 } ], colors: [ { r: 1, a: 1 }, { g: 1, a: 1 } ] }"`

If you `rostopic echo` this, it should be the same as what you have posted in your question.

[image]